# How to combine Trigonometric identity $\sin(x)+\cos(5x)$ using Euler's formula

Tags: trigonometry

I am having this question about how to combine $\sin(x)+\cos(5x) =A\sin(x+\theta$)

I am thinking maybe I could use Euler's formula to do it but failed. Could anyone give me a hint or explain how to do this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The sum of sinusoids of different frequencies is never a sinusoid.

Comment: This can be done for $\sin x + 5 \cos x,$ but not for $\sin x + \cos (5x).$

Answer (score 0):

By picture, your function has several local minima and maxima in $0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi.$ It cannot be expressed as $a \sin (x+b)$

[image]